# Offloading jQuery to its own file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm confused on consolidating jQuery into it's own file.   I'm able to do what I need with jQuery, but I either put each function in its own .js.erb file, or include it inline in the .html.erb file, wrapped with script tags.  If I try to put them all in the same file, I can't get it to work.

I want to `replaceWith()` a different `div` whenever the user clicks on a link, specific to which link it is.  Currently, I have each link pointing to a different action, each with it's own distinct .js.erb file - so I have about 12 files, each with only one link of jQuery - which works, but seems so messy.

An example link is like so:

```
<%= link_to({:action => 'economics'}, remote: true) do %><div id="department" class="economics">Economics</div><% end %>
```

And the assosiated jQuery (again this is the only line in the file economics.js.erb):

```
$('#target_div').replaceWith('<%= j render "economics" %>')
```

I feel like there has to be a cleaner way to do this.

---

I got it to work thanks to the comments below!  Here is the general code

HTML - data-remote was the key!

```
<div id="render_form" data-target="target_div" data-remote="true"> economics </div>
<div id="render_form" data-target="target_div" data-remote="true"> other </div>
<hr />
<div id="target_div">Nil</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("div#render_form").click(function() {
    var targetId = $(this).data("target");
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (targetId.length > 0) {
        $(this).data("target");
        $('#' + targetId).text(text);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle can be found here!](http://jsfiddle.net/QMDcz/)

Thanks for the comments!

Comment: If you need to rewrite the same chunk of code 12 times, don't you think you should be changing the way you write your JavaScript? Can you post your rendered HTML and your current JS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shot in the dark as I'm not familiar with Ruby but from what I understand, you can add the target div ID to each source div:

```
<div id="department" class="economics" data-target="economics_target_div">
```

Then have this single block of jQuery code in your main file:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div[data-target]").click(function() {
        var targetId = $(this).data("target");
        if (targetId.length > 0) {
            //prevent replacing again:
            $(this).data("target", "");
            $('#' + targetId).replaceWith(this);
        }
    });
});
```

This will iterate through all DIVs having the above data attribute and handle their click event.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/QMDcz/).

Comment: Great - the data-target was the key!  Thanks!  I also posted the final code for what I was trying to achieve in case you were curious :D

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help and glad it's only pure JS/jQuery otherwise I would have been pretty much helpless. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a jQuery expert, but in general, I like to separate all javascript for a single view into a single file rather than include them inline.

I believe this is the "Railsy" way to do it. A JS file for each view, ideally. Check out this blog on some more general info (http://xn--ncoder-9ua.dk/blog/2012/02/page-specific-javascript-in-rails-3/)

Now, when I do so, I also make sure to wrap the JS in `$(document.ready(function()...` to ensure that the script is run on pageload. Try that, and see if it works for you.

Comment: Rails asset pipeline let you have all your javascript in a single file and it's great. But it also means you code your js properly so that no interferences happen. That's where js frameworks come in handy.